# Bytefields: horizontally align leftwordgroup

Tags: bytefield

My leftwordgroups look pretty ugly in my bytefields. Is it possible to make the same gap between bytefield and leftwordgroup as between bytefield and rightwordgroup? Or is it at least possible, to make the gap between leftwordgroup and bytefield a little bit bigger?

This is my current code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,naustrian,DIV=12,BCOR=1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcommand{\flexnumfield}{{FlexNum, 1 -- 9 Bytes}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Bytefield}
\needspace{2\baselineskip}\begin{figure}\centering\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2.2em]{8} \\ 
\bitheader{0-7} \\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedright Message Type}}
\wordbox[lrt]{1}{9}

\end{rightwordgroup}
\\ 
\begin{leftwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedleft Versionsverlauf}}
\wordbox[lrt]{3}{Version Count \\ \flexnumfield \\ $\vdots$}
\\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedright Version}}
\wordbox[lrtb]{3}{Hash \\ Data, 20 Bytes \\ $\vdots$}

\end{rightwordgroup}
 \\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedright Version}}
\wordbox[lrtb]{1}{$\vdots$}

\end{rightwordgroup}

\end{leftwordgroup}
\end{bytefield}\par\protect\caption{some caption} 
\label{bytefield}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: ugly leftwordgroup]

Comment: Please provide a complete Minimum Working Example, beginning with `\documentclass`.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thank you for adding full code... but it still does not compile.  Things like `\code` and `\flexnumfield` are undefined...but are they necessary to define the "problem"?

Comment: It should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a strange asymmetry between left and right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=12,BCOR=1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\newcommand{\flexnumfield}{{FlexNum, 1 -- 9 Bytes}}

\begin{document}

\begin{bytefield}[
  bitwidth=2.2em,
  rightcurlyspace=0pt,
  leftcurlyspace=12pt
]{8} \\ 
\bitheader{0-7} \\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{Message Type}
\wordbox[lrt]{1}{9}
\end{rightwordgroup}
\\ 
\begin{leftwordgroup}{Versionsverlauf}
\wordbox[lrt]{3}{Version Count \\ \flexnumfield \\ $\vdots$}
\\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{Version}
\wordbox[lrtb]{3}{Hash \\ Data, 20 Bytes \\ $\vdots$}
\end{rightwordgroup}
\\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{Version}
\wordbox[lrtb]{1}{$\vdots$}
\end{rightwordgroup}
\end{leftwordgroup}
\end{bytefield}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of specifying the values in the optional argument to the environment, you can define the spaces globally (or locally inside an environment like `figure` or `table`) by saying

```
\bytefieldsetup{
  rightcurlyspace=0pt,
  leftcurlyspace=12pt
}
```

in the preamble (or in the environment).

Answer (score 3):

Here I applied a patch to the environment, adding 12pt to the left using these lines of code:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endleftwordgroup}{-\total@lbox@width}{-12pt -\total@lbox@width}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,ngerman,naustrian,DIV=12,BCOR=1cm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\endleftwordgroup}{-\total@lbox@width}{-12pt -\total@lbox@width}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\flexnumfield}{{FlexNum, 1 -- 9 Bytes}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Bytefield}
\needspace{2\baselineskip}\begin{figure}\centering\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=2.2em]{8} \\ 
\bitheader{0-7} \\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedright Message Type}}
\wordbox[lrt]{1}{9}

\end{rightwordgroup}
\\ 
\begin{leftwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedleft Versionsverlauf}}
\wordbox[lrt]{3}{Version Count \\ \flexnumfield \\ $\vdots$}
\\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedright Version}}
\wordbox[lrtb]{3}{Hash \\ Data, 20 Bytes \\ $\vdots$}

\end{rightwordgroup}
 \\ 
\begin{rightwordgroup}{\parbox{8em}{\raggedright Version}}
\wordbox[lrtb]{1}{$\vdots$}

\end{rightwordgroup}

\end{leftwordgroup}
\end{bytefield}\par\protect\caption{some caption} 
\label{bytefield}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]